# Realm List下のデータを写したい

Tags: swift, realm, swift5

swiftを初めて２ヶ月程の初心者です。
RealmにてListの下にある同じデータ型のデータをコピーしたいと思っているのですが、
その方法が分からず困っております。どなたかお力を貸して頂けるとありがたいです。

実現したいこと
Realmで下図のGroup.registmembersに登録されている内容をEvent.addmembersにコピーしたい。

[image: Realm1]

[image: Realm2]

```
//Model
class Group: Object {
    @objc dynamic var title: String = ""
    let events = List<Event>()
    let registmembers = List<Member>()
    }

class Event: Object {
    @objc dynamic var title: String = ""
    var var addmembers = List<SelectMember>()
    var parentGroup = LinkingObjects(fromType: Group.self, property: "events")
}

class Member: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var furigana: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var done: Bool = false
    @objc dynamic var gender: Bool = false
}

class SelectMember : Object {
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var furigana: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var done: Bool = false
    @objc dynamic var gender: Bool = false
}
```

```
//ViewController
    var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let realm = try! Realm()
    var selectedEvent : Event?
    var group : Group?
    var member : List<Member>?
    

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //選択したグループの値をappDelegateで持ってきて代入
    group = appDelegate.selectgroup
　　//グループに登録されているメンバーの値をmemberに代入
　　member? = group?.registmembers as! List<Member>
　　try! realm.write {
　　 //選択したイベントのメンバーにグループのメンバーを追加する
    selectedEvent?.addmembers.append(member)
//ここでCannot convert value of type 'List<Member>?' to expected argument type 'SelectMember'というエラーが出ます。
　　}
}
```

質問をご覧頂きありがとうございます。
説明不足な点などありましたらすみません。
回答をお持ちしています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Cannot convert value of type 'List?' to expected argument type 'SelectMember'

というエラーが出ていると思いますが、エラーの通りで `Event.addmembers` の型は `List<SelectMember>` となっており、一方 `Group.registmembers`  は `List<Member>` となっているため `append` で代入することができる `SelectMember` と型が一致しないためエラーになっています。

今回のエラーを解決するためには以下の方法が考えられます。

- そもそも `Member` と `SelectMember` はほとんど同じ形なので、二つに分けず `Member` で統一する
- どうしても分ける必要がある場合は `Member` から `SelectMember` に逐一変換して `append()` する

個人的には1つめの `Member` で統一する方法をお勧めします。

が、分けなければいけない場合もあると思うので、参考として変換する場合のコードを書いてみました。
載せていただいたコードから推測する形で書かせていただいたので、こちらのミスで動かない場合もあると思います。

```swift
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // 選択したグループの値を appDelegate から持ってきて代入
    let selectGroup = appDelegate.selectgroup

    // グループに登録されているメンバー一覧の値を取り出し
    let registMembers = group.registmembers
    
    try! realm.write {
        // forEach で `List<Member>` の要素分ループを回し、`SelectMember` に変換して追加
        registMembers.forEach { member in
            // `SelectMember` に変換
            // 以下の部分は少し冗長なので `Member` に変換用のメソッドを持たせてもいいと思います.
            let selectMember = SelectMember()
            selectMember.name = member.name
            selectMember.furigana = member.furigana
            selectMember.done = member.done
            selectMember.gender = member.gender

            // 変換した `SelectMember` を `append()` で追加
            selectedEvent?.addmembers.append(selectMember)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hybsbsさん　お忙しい中ご回答頂きありがとうございます。教えて頂いたregistmemberを変換する方法で保存することが出来ました！イベントごとにメンバーの情報を取得したかったので今回は分けて作成しておりました。大変助かりました。ありがとうございます！